# A basic conjecture/observation on the Riemann $\xi$-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Based on computations I have made the following mini-conjecture: For any zeta zero $s_0$ with $|s_0|\geq|1-s_0|$ and for $0<\tau<1$ define $M_\tau=|s_0|(1+(1-\tau)^2)$. Let
$\xi$ stand for the Riemann xi-function then

$\lim_{\tau \to 1} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |\xi(\tau s_0-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta}) |d\theta=-\lim_{\tau \to 1}  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log | \xi(\tau s_0+1-\tau-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta}) |d\theta$

What tools could possibly be fruitful to study such a question? I have tried the Hadamard factorization for $\xi$ which led me to this observation/conjecture.

Comment: Why do these limits exist?   PS On the Riemann hypothesis, for nontrivial zeros $|s_0|=|1-s_0|$, so your first assumption $\ge$ is superflous.

Comment: Briefly, I use the following formula applied to appropriately chosen discs $M_\tau$  and $f_\tau$ : For $f$ be analytic on the disc $\overline{D}(0,R)$ centred at $0$ with radius $R>0$ and such that $f(0)\neq 0$, then the following formula is well-known
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\theta}\log(|f(Re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}R\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\rho}\left(\frac{R}{\rho}-\frac{\overline{\rho}}{R} \right)
\end{align}

where $\rho$ are the roots in $D(0,R)$

Comment: @Stopple Aprori, the assumption $|s_0|\geq|1-s_0|$ is not superfluous, because we don't know $|s_0|=|1-s_0|$ unconditionally. Of course it is possible that one can get rid of this assumption, e.g. by using that $1-s_0$ is also a zeta zero.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow

Answer (score 6):

Consider any analytic function $f$ and a zero $s_0 \ne 0$ say simple, though things do not really change if there is a multiplicity as below. Then for some $c \ne 0$ we have $f(s)=f(s_0)+c(s-s_0)+O(|s-s_0|^2)$.

If $\tau=1-\epsilon$ we have $\tau s_0-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta}-s_0=\epsilon (-s_0-(1+\epsilon)^2|s_0|e^{i\theta})$ with $|-s_0-(1+\epsilon)^2|s_0|e^{i\theta}| \le 5|s_0|$ say so we have $f((\tau s_0-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta})=c\epsilon(-s_0-(1+\epsilon)^2|s_0|e^{i\theta}+O(\epsilon))$ uniformly in $\theta$ hence taking logarithms and integrating against the $\cos \theta$ we obtain that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |f(\tau s_0-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta}) |d\theta=$$$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)(\log |-s_0-(1+\epsilon)^2|s_0|e^{i\theta}+O(\epsilon) |)d\theta$$ hence we can pass to the limit and get that $$\lim_{\tau \to 1} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |f(\tau s_0-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta}) |d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |-s_0-|s_0|e^{i\theta} |d\theta=\pi\Re \frac{s_0}{|s_0|}$$ which follows taking the real part from the well known formula ($g$ analytic for $|z| \le R$ and $g(0) \ne 0$) $$\begin{align} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\theta}\log(|g(Re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}R\frac{g'(0)}{g(0)}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{g(\rho)=0, |\rho|<R}\left(\frac{R}{\rho}-\frac{\overline{\rho}}{R} \right) \end{align}$$ applied to $g(z)=z+e^{i\arg s_0}$ and $R \to 1^-$ as there are no roots and $\Re e^{-i\arg s_0}=\frac{s_0}{|s_0|}$ etc

Similarly one gets $$\lim_{\tau \to 1} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |f(\tau s_0+1-\tau-M_\tau(1-\tau)e^{i\theta}) |d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |1-s_0-|s_0|e^{i\theta} |d\theta$$

If now we assume $|s_0| > |1-s_0|$ so the function $z-\frac{1-s_0}{|s_0|}$ has a zero inside the unit disc, the result above gives that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(\theta)\log |1-s_0-|s_0|e^{i\theta} |d\theta=\pi \Re \frac{\bar s_0-1}{|s_0|}$$ and this is easily seen to hold in the limit too when $|s_0| = |1-s_0|$

So if the relation in the OP holds for $f, s_0$ we get that $\Re (1-\bar s_0)=\Re s_0$ or $\Re s_0=1/2$ and in particular the OP so called mini-conjecture is equivalent to RH and the question becomes just a fairly simple though unnecessarily obscured  equivalence to RH

Comment: In the second line of your displayed equation, what happened to the leading term $c\epsilon$ in your expression for $f$?  (In the OP question, if you formally plug in $\tau=1$, you have a term $\log|\xi(s_0)|$, which is undefined.)  I'm confused?

Comment: we have $\log |(c\epsilon H(\theta)|=\log |c\epsilon|+\log |H(\theta)|$ and integrating against $\cos \theta$ cancels the $\log |c\epsilon|$

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!